# using a lot of middlewares and pass paramters between middlewares by amending req object

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am working on a project and every endpoint in the application is heavily relaying on the middlewares, Sign up endpoint has more than 10 middlewars. Here is what signup endpoint looks like:

1. Verify Signup token
2. Verify Security Code
3. Validate
4. Check if Username is unique
5. Lock Username
6. Save in the database
7. Save in the Redis
8. Set SSO token
9. Invalidate Signup Token
10. Build Response
11. Create Refferal Link
12. Add notification to the database
13. Send Notification
14. Error handler

14 middleware for the signup endpoint. I am really bothered by this approach. I don't think it is a good approach and I want to get your opinion on this.

- What flaws do you see in this approach?
- What are the disadvantages?
- Do you think it would have impact on performance?

Comment: group them to one middleware, then

Comment: lets say first four middlewares are mostly used together, then group them to new middleware like `authMiddleware` and use it where necessary